# Game keeps crashing my Intel 7733, even though the graphics chip should be able to handle it

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, cpu, crash, gpu

I recently obtained Warframe, and it crashes my laptop as soon as I get to the point where you either log in or sign up. I changed my default graphics chip for the game from my `Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620` to the `NVIDIA GeForce MX150` also present in my machine.

I checked to see if it was the now the chip the game operates off of, and it indeed is. However, when I run it, it still crashes before I can get into the game and lower the graphics settings, or even sign up.

Have I done something wrong, or am I not able to play games like this? I did my research, and it seems that the game should run just fine on an MX150, even on high settings, and my i7 processor should handle anything CPU related just fine. What's going on?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the game or your driver. A game can run slow or show an error message. But never crash. Did you download the latest drive from nvidia.com? Also try to update your game.

Comment: There really isn't any indication at this point that your problem is with GPU firepower, so while that may be the issue, we can't tell from what is presented. I'd start here: https://digitalextremes.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/212890418-What-should-I-do-if-my-game-keeps-crashing-
Also note, other people seem to have a similar problem. is it the same?  https://forums.warframe.com/topic/1026308-bug-whole-thing-crashes-midway-through-the-loading-screen/

Comment: @somega that is what I'm currently doing, we'll see if that fixes.

Comment: @FrankThomas possibly, but I don't see a solution in that thread. I suppose that's a common issue with games, the users find issues but the devs don't pay attention unless it's a big enough problem.

Comment: do you use Discord with the game? some people seem to be having (or were at one time) having trouble with that. check out this article (but note they;re trying to sell you an unneeded driver update, so don;t fall for that): https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/2020-tips-how-to-fix-warframe-crashing/ in particular do you have any of the software listed in fix 3 installed? seems like a lot of stuff wont work with this game.